# Redirect error when decorating Controller with Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I'm working on an asp.net MVC 4 app using VS 2011. I have a custom role provider with a custom AuthorizeAttribute to determine the user's roles that will redirect to an access denied page if they aren't a member of the particular role. What I've done so far works when I decorate any controller action with the custom attribute, but it fails with different errors in IE and FF when I add the attribute to the controller. My custom attribute:

```
public class AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string RedirectActionName { get; set; }
    public string RedirectControllerName { get; set; }
    private IAccountRepository _accountRepository;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var user = httpContext.User;
        this._accountRepository = new AccountRepository();
        var accessAllowed = false;    
        var allowedRoles = this.Roles.Split(',');

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Get roles for current user
        var roles = this._accountRepository.GetRoles(user.Identity.Name);

        foreach (var allowedRole in allowedRoles)
        {
            if (roles.Contains(allowedRole))
            {
                accessAllowed = true;
            }
        }

        if (!accessAllowed)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {   
            var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = this.RedirectActionName == "" ? "AccessDenied" : this.RedirectActionName,
                controller = this.RedirectControllerName == "" ? "Home" : this.RedirectControllerName
            });

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
        }
    }
}
```

I also add a global attribute in RegisterGlobalFilters (I tried removing this but still get the same issues):

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

When I decorate an action with the attribute it works fine:

```
[AccessDeniedAuthorize(RedirectActionName = "AccessDenied", RedirectControllerName = "Home", Roles = "propdat")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.ViewBag.Message = "Welcome.";

    return this.View();
}
```

But when I add it to the Controller it breaks completely:

```
[AccessDeniedAuthorize(RedirectActionName = "AccessDenied", RedirectControllerName = "Home", Roles = "propdat")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.ViewBag.Message = "Welcome.";

        return this.View();
    }

    public ActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        this.ViewBag.Message = "You are not authorised to view this page. Please contact your administrator.";

        return this.View();            
    }
}
```

The roles are returned from my database via a repository which seems fine. In IE I get the standard "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error, and a pretty strange one in Firefox:

> **The page isn't redirecting properly**
>          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> - This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
>     cookies.

In IE the url remains at the Home url:

```
http://localhost:1989
```

but FF performs the redirect as the url changes to the view that I specify in the attribute:

```
http://localhost:1989/Home/AccessDenied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Look at your code again dude :)**

You're decorating the `HomeController` with your `AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute` but your `HomeController` contains your `AccessDenied` action which couldn't be Denied.

So the problem is whenever `AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute` tries to redirect current user to the `AccessDenied` Action `accessAllowed` will be false and that will load you to circular loop.

**the solution is :**

Either put your `AccessDenied` Action in another "HelperController" and don't decorate this HelperController with your Attribute.

Or just add this Attribute to all Actions in the `HomeController` except the `AccessDenied` Action.

Comment: I thought that was the point of the [AllowAnnoymous] attribute...so you can decorate your controller with the [Authorize] attribute and have all methods restricted EXCEPT those decorated with [AllowAnnoymous] - is that not the case?

Comment: @JTech I think you are right as well. But to be honest I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is:

1. Remove the global filter - what this will do is lock down every action on every MVC controller (not WebAPI) - enforcing that if the user is not authenticated or not authorized, then the framework will return a Redirect to the 'login url' setting (found in the authentication >  forms element - assuming you're using Forms authentication) - note that the global filter will not be using the redirect url in your custom attribute.
2. Place your custom attribute on the home controller and then add the [AllowAnnoymous] attribute to the AccessDenied action AND most importantly, add this code to your custom attribute (which is required to ensure it skips actions with the [AllowAnnoymous] attribute):

   ```
       bool skipAuthorization = 
       filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true) 
       || 
       filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

       if (skipAuthorization)
       {
           return;
       }
   ```

BTW what Firefox is telling you is that you're getting an infinite redirect loop...because the initial request was unauthorized, framework redirects to login url, but that request gets caught by the Authorization check and itself gets redirected...and so on and so on until the browser gives up and stops the loop.